# saving random letters of an array as a String

Tags: java, string

I wanna write a program in which different letters of a String Array form different words based on random orders. The most important part is that letters should not be duplicate in one word. I could somehow make the correct pattern but the problem is that I can only show them on console and couldn't find a way to save them as a String (like "OMAN"). Here is my code :

```
int size = 4;
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
Random rnd = new Random();
while (list.size()<size) {
    int random = rnd.nextInt(size);
    if (!list.contains(random)) {
        list.add(random);
    }
}
String[] words = {"M","O","A","N"};
for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
    System.out.println(words[list.get(i)]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First declare a blank string

```
String answer = "";
```

Then in your for loop do

```
answer+=words[list.get(i)];
```

When you leave the for loop

```
System.out.println(answer);
```

Will have what you want. To do it more efficiently I'd read up on StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

You could accumulate them to a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
    sb.append(words[list.get(i)]);
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
    int size = 4;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while (list.size() < size) {
        int random = rnd.nextInt(size);
        if (!list.contains(random)) {
            list.add(random);
        }
    }
    String[] words = {"M", "O", "A", "N"};
    String finalWord = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        finalWord += words[list.get(i)];
    }
    System.out.println(finalWord);
```